# Adding a tag inside repetitive node through xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am looking for xslt code which would do the following:

Input xml:

```
<Profile>
<Name>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Cena</LastName>
<Name>
<Name>
<FirstName>Shane</FirstName>
<LastName>Warne</LastName>
<Name>
<Name>
<FirstName>Brett</FirstName>
<LastName>Lee</LastName>
<Name>
</Profile>
```

I want to add a tag MiddleName inside each Name node.

Output xml:

```
<Profile>
<Name>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Cena</LastName>
<MiddleName>A</MiddleName>
<Name>
<Name>
<FirstName>Shane</FirstName>
<LastName>Warne</LastName>
<MiddleName>B</MiddleName>
<Name>
<Name>
<FirstName>Brett</FirstName>
<LastName>Lee</LastName>
<MiddleName>C</MiddleName>
<Name>
</Profile>
```

Comment: Start with the [Identity Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) and then insert the extra nodes where appropriate.  You haven't said how you'll determine the correct middle initial, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Both the input and output document of this question are malformed, and you do not show any of your XSLT code. Also, it is unclear what you are asking in the first place. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Use an identity template, plus this:

```
<xsl:template match="Name">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <MiddleName>
            <!-- code to insert middle name -->
        </MiddleName>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```